# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't wake up after suspension with latest drivers installed

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, suspend

I have reinstalled my Ubuntu 18.04 today and the one issue I keep struggling with is that it doesn't wake up after suspension. I had the same issue with my laptop previously but updating to the newest drivers solved it. Now the drivers are up-to-date but the issue persists. The `nvidia-smi` output is below:

```
Wed Feb  5 16:55:36 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.48.02    Driver Version: 440.48.02    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2060    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   43C    P8     2W /  N/A |    223MiB /  5926MiB |      4%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1249      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            18MiB |
|    0      1310      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          13MiB |
|    0      1499      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           113MiB |
|    0      1644      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          74MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Why not use the driver that used to work?

Comment: It stopped working after a while anyway (that's why I finally decided to reinstall Ubuntu) and unfortunetely I don't have an idea which one it was.

Comment: I keep track of versions that work and avoid changes until hardware changes. You can search your GPU to find what versions work with fewest bugs.